# configuring jest and enzyme in existing project is throwing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, babel-jest

I am working in an existing react project and I want to introduce unit testing in it. For this, I am configuring `jest` with `enzyme`. In `package.json`, I have added below:

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>src/setupTests.js"],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "/node_modules"
    ]
  },
```

and to `yarn test`, I have below:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "run-s dev",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
    "debug": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config webpack.debug.js",
    "build": "run-s lint build:no-lint",
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

I have `setupTests.js` as well in which `enzyme` is configured:

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

**Now, when I run `yarn test`, I am getting below error:**

```
yarn run v1.12.3
$ jest
 FAIL  src/components/__tests__/TroveV5.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'source-map-support' from 'source-map-support.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:230:17)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.352s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**Cannot find module 'source-map-support' from 'source-map-support.js'**

What am I doing wrong?